# Bug: E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Hello of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm getting this when I click my login button and I have no idea why, I don't know why it says Hello in the error and I searched my whole project and can't find the occurrence of "Hello". Is there another cause for this error?

```
public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();




    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxx";



    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // setup input fields
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        // setup buttons
        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

        // register listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.login:
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
                break;
            case R.id.register:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    // save user data
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
                    Editor edit = sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("username", username);
                    edit.commit();

                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Edited code

```
<?php
       if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}


//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");




if (!empty($_POST)) {
$query = "SELECT id,password, username, iv FROM users WHERE username = :username";




    $username = $_POST['username'];

    //encrypting the username and password to compare to the ones stored in the databaase



 $query_params = array(
        ':username' => $username,
    );

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);


    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    }




    //fetching all the rows from the query

        $password = $_POST['password'];

    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    $key = $row['iv'];
    $encrypted_password = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $secret_key, $password, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $key); 
 if ($row) {
        if ($encrypted_password == $row['password']) {


            $login_ok = true;
        }
    }

    if ($login_ok) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Login successful!";
        die(json_encode($response));
       echo json_encode($response);



    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

} else {
?>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <form action="login.php" method="post">
                    Username:<br />
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
                    <br /><br />
                    Password:<br />
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" />
                    <br /><br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                </form>
                <a href="register.php">Register</a>
        <?php
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be something wrong with your JSONParser class or response from the server might be returning "hello". Could you post that class as well to make things more clearer.

Comment: I found the hello string, it was a small echo that I deleted. I am getting this now, "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
04"

Comment: The JSON response is {"success":1,"message":"Login successful!"}

Comment: I think you are not getting proper response from your server. Check if the server side is returning a proper result for your login query.

Comment: Is this not it? {"success":1,"message":"Login successful!"}

Comment: Yes it is. Are you still getting the parsing exception? Could you post the latest exception log?

Comment: Yeah I am. Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
04-08 19:46:09.627  17823-18176/com.example.strobe.coffeetime E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5

Comment: your response contains <br.... use log to see what is server response in JSONParser class before parsing and getting JSONObject. Could you post JSONParser code aswell.

Comment: Did you look by printing log? Try printing final result in stringbuilder. i m sure somehow you are getting wrong response from server. Appside looks fine.

Comment: Anything I try after  JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                        params); doesn't display. So it's happening here but I don't know why.

Comment: use log to view response at line#76 in JSONParser class

Comment: Use the default android log. Another thing you can do is put breakpoint at line#76 and debug

Comment: Still the same  Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
04-08 21:04:53.916    2716-2883/com.example.strobe.coffeetime E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3 so frustrating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74753/discussion-between-samir-and-strobes).